# Why my code can't work and no error message?

Tags: haskell

I'm new in Haskell and I tried following for practice. It does not have error but it cannot work and crush the program.
Can anyone tell me why?

```
type Weight_value = Float
data Weight_unit = G | KG | T
    deriving (Show, Eq)
data Weight = Weight {value :: Weight_value, unit :: Weight_unit}
    deriving (Show)
instance Eq Weight where
    weight_left == weight_right = 
        convert weight_left KG == convert weight_right KG

to_g :: Weight -> Weight
to_g weight = case weight of
    Weight gram G   -> Weight gram G
    Weight kilo KG  -> Weight (kilo*1000) G
    Weight tone T   -> Weight (tone*1000000)G

to_kg :: Weight -> Weight
to_kg weight = case weight of
    Weight gram G   -> Weight (gram/1000) KG
    Weight kilo KG  -> Weight kilo KG
    Weight tone T   -> Weight (tone*1000) KG

to_t :: Weight ->Weight
to_t weight = case weight of
    Weight gram G   -> Weight (gram/1000000) T
    Weight kilo KG  -> Weight (kilo/1000) T
    Weight tone T   -> Weight tone T

convert :: Weight -> Weight_unit -> Weight
convert weight unit = case unit of
    G       -> to_g         weight
    KG      -> to_kg        weight
    T       -> to_t         weight
```

Comment: You may want to read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: more details about what exactly "crush program" means would be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much simpler if you define all your conversion factors in one place:

```
cf :: Weight_unit -> Weight_unit -> Float
cf G KG = 1 / 1000
cf G T = 1/1000000
cf KG T = 1/1000
cf KG G = 1000
cf T KG = 1000
cf T G = 1000000
cf _ _ = 1
```

Now, your `convert` function just needs to call `cf` using the current and target units:

```
convert :: Weight -> Weight_unit -> Weight
convert (Weight v u1) u2 = Weight (v*(cf u1 u2)) u2
```